# Models / Entities vs complex types

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a problem understanding complex data types vs entities in ASP MVC and C#. I started by creating the following type, which is not meant to be an entity (DB table):

```
public class Period : IPeriod
{
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }
}
```

I added this type to a model:

```
public class Event
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public Period EventTime { get; set; }
}
```

This worked fine. It seemed to understand that Period is a complex type, but not an entity. It just added the columns EventTime_From and EventTime_To to the Event table.

However, then I added some complexity to the Period type by removing the interface, moving the class to a different namespace and adding methods to the class. Suddenly, when trying to rebuild the database, it was suddenly interpreted as an entitytype, thus throwing an Exception for missing a primary key.

What is the system here? When are classes seen as complex types, and when are they seen as entities?

Comment: Instead of modifying Period, did you try creating a child class of Period with the implementation, or making Period a partial class and putting the implementation in the other partial, somewhere else?

Comment: I'm certainly no expert on what's happening behind the scenes with the Entity model generator, though I have some experience with similar problems. The models have resource files where they define the object to table mappings. The automated model generator has made an incorrect inference (it's attempting to map Period to some table or create one if it doesn't exist) which you'll have to correct by hand in one of the resource files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to say what exactly is going on without knowing all changes you made but you can always tell EF explicitly that `Period` is a complex type by either marking it with `ComplexType` attribute or by using fluent mapping:

```
modelBuilder.ComplexType<Period>();
```